# Как разрешить доступ к урлу только через впн соединение

Tags: linux, iptables

Установил Wireguard. В системе два интерфейса - `wg0` и `ens3`. Хочу заблочить доступ к порту 8888, и разрешить к нему доступ только через `wg0` интерфейс

```
-A INPUT -s 10.20.0.0/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -I INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

А потом дроп на нужный порт. У вас там `.0/32` которое работать не будет - укажите правильную маску